# Piping a script with "read" to bash

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, read

I need to run a script by piping it through `bash` with `wget`(rather than running it directly with bash).

```
$ wget -O - http://example.com/my-script.sh | bash
```

It's not working because my script has `read` statements in it. For some reason these don't work when piping to bash:

```
# Piping to bash works in general
$ echo 'hi'
hi
$ echo "echo 'hi'" | bash
hi

# `read` works directly
$ read -p "input: " var
input: <prompt>

# But not when piping - returns immediately
$ echo 'read -p "input: " var' | bash
$
```

Instead of prompting `input:` and asking for a value as it should, the read command just gets passed over by `bash`.

Does anyone know how I can pipe a script with `read` to `bash`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`read` reads from standard input. But the standard input of the bash process is already taken by the script. Depending on the shell, either `read` won't read anything because the shell has already read and parsed the whole script, or `read` will consume unpredictable lines in the script.

Simple solution:

```
bash -c "$(wget -O - http://example.com/my-script.sh)"
```

More complex solution, more for education purposes than to illustrate a good solution for this particular scenario:

```
echo '{ exec </dev/tty; wget -O - http://example.com/my-script.sh; }' | bash
```

Answer (score 3):

Process substitution will do what you want:

`bash <(wget ...)`

That said, I have to question your motivation here.  If you control the webserver (and use https) then maybe this might make sense.  But just running a script from the internet blind is very risky.

Comment: `just running a script from the internet blind is very risky` - aye we know it's risky, but people can choose to trust scripts from certain organisations. See the discussion in comments on @Xen2050's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with :

```
wget -O tmpscript.sh http://example.com/my-script.sh
chmod +x tmpscript.sh
tmpscript.sh
```

?

Comment: 'cos then I have to create a file. I mean it'd work, it's just a bit messy.

Comment: True. Though that's a good reason to use `/tmp`, lots of programs use temp files. I'd be leary of running any downloaded scripts immediately without taking a look first...

Comment: Well that's your call. Plenty of projects offer these one-liners, e.g. [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/), [ohmyzsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) and others I can't remember right now. In this case it's a setup script I want to run on new systems from my own repository. I'm not too worried about its contents, as I wrote it.

Comment: I'm thinking of anyone else finding this question (a totally new user perhaps) might not know any better.